# connecting to local MS SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jtds

I have a local MS SQL Server and I am trying to connect to it using JTDS in java.  Here is the connection string:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/stock","sa","password");
```

And the server properties:
name: USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS
root directory: c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL

I am getting a `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect` error.

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Connectionstrings... Service Unavailable. HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: "Connection refused" typically means that either there's nothing listening on that port or a firewall is actively blocking your connection. Since you're connecting to localhost, I'd guess the former. Try connecting with a "native" SQL Server tool (i.e. management studio or sqlcmd) to boil it down to the simplest thing you can try.

Comment: @BenThul i can connect through management studio just fine

Comment: @Mike: When you connect, are you using "localhost,1433" as the server name? Making sure we're comparing apples to apples.

Comment: @BenThul USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS is the server name

Comment: @Mike: That's fine. I'd still try doing it my way since that's essentially what you're doing in your java connection string. Either that or change your java connection string. Like I said compare apples/apples.

Comment: Yes try "localhost,1433" and "Sql Authentication" in SSMS to mimic how your Java app connects.

Comment: Open CMD And run : sqlcmd -S Server\Instance Then, what is the output?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the following:

- You have enabled mixed mode security, i.e. so you can connect with username/password (rather than using Windows authentication)
- The TCP/IP protocol is enabled. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager, then in SQL Server Network config select Protocols and Enable TCP/IP.
- Try passing just one String to getConnection using this format:

  ```
  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/stock;instance=SQLEXPRESS;user=sa;password=password")
  ```
- If you are using this format (naming the instance) then the SQL Server Browser service needs to be running (in Services). If this is greyed out then the Service is probably disabled, so enable it and then start it.

Comment: with that change the error is now `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Unable to get information from SQL Server: localhost.`

Comment: Have you definitely enabled TCP/IP? See http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#instanceGetInfo

Comment: The TCP/IP is definitely enabled and the fire wall was pulled down and it still wont connect.

Comment: Bit of a random thought- try using 127.0.01 instead of localhost

Comment: Another thought- is the SQL Server Browser service running? It needs to be for TCP/IP connections

Comment: SQL Server Browser is not running, how do i start it?

Comment: it is, but start stop, pause, restart and resume are grayed out

Comment: @Martin Wilson i am also having same problem for MS SQL server 2000

Comment: SQL Server Browser is not in services

Answer (score 0):

Port 1433 is the port used by the default instance.  You're using SQLEXPRESS, which is a named instance.  Your connection string should include something like:

```
sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Browser service is disable by default. If you're developing .Net app, you do not need to start SQLBrowser, but if you're using JTDS in java, you will need it started.